# Playlist on ipod nano 5th gen

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

I have been trying to sync my playlists from itunes with my new ipod nano 5th gen, but the podcasts don't sync (they did sync on my old 2nd gen).  Any suggestions for how to fix this?

The music playlists sync as do the podcasts, but the playlists with only podcasts don't sync.  I sync automatically when plugging into my Macbook Pro with iTunes version 10.
I don't have any playlists that have both podcasts and non-podcasts.

Comment: Do the problem playlists combine podcasts and non-podcasts?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to provide more details (are you getting any error messages? Are you manually managing you iPod's music or automatically?) but here's the best place to look:

Connect your iPod to your computer, fire up iTunes and click your nano's icon on the left of the iTunes window. Look for the podcasts tab and make sure the sync Podcasts and 'automatically sync podcast' tick boxes are selected.

There's a really clear step-by-step [here.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1351)